# How to transform a variable and a number into a variable?

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate some random content, where the content of a given element is inserted following this logic:

**Variables:** 
$s1 = 'var(--vimeo)'; 
$s2 = 'var(--youtube)'; ...

**Content to be changed randomly:** 
`figure:before { content: <?php echo $s . random_int(1, 22); ?>;}`
**Return:** 
figure:before { content: number; }

**Wish:** 
figure:before { content: var(--vimeo) or ...;}

What I tried to do was to join a variable with a value and thus get a variable, but due to my lack of knowledge and very low experience in php I got a not favorable return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your variables into an array, like

```
$s = ["var(--vimeo)", "var(--youtube)", ...];
```

Then do

```
content: <?=$s[rand(0, count($s)-1)]?>;
```

Otherwise you would have to use `eval()`

```
content: <?php eval('echo $s' . rand(1, 22)); ?>;
```

Comment: You would not have to use the actual `eval`, PHP has a concept of [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) ... those are a bit "eval-adjacent", but still a little less dangerous.